# How to use updateProfile in firebase / Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I want to update a user's displayName and/or photo URL in firebase. I am using angular. I have a service that handles the auth stuff and it works OK for login/register/etc. I have created another service to handle the user data (UserService). However, when I try to call the updateProfile function, I get the compile error below. The [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#updateprofile) show the function being called through a user object, but it doesn't explain what that user object is.

The error

```
error TS2339: Property 'updateProfile' does not exist on type 'AngularFireAuth'
```

I have tried this a number of ways - including the one below that produces the error above as well as created a user object with the currentUser function and then trying to call the method on that object. Nothing seems to work.

```
import { Injectable, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from "app/main/services/users";
import { auth } from 'firebase/app';
import { AngularFireAuth } from "@angular/fire/auth";
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreDocument } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Router } from "@angular/router";


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {

  constructor(
        public afs: AngularFirestore,   // Inject Firestore service
        public afAuth: AngularFireAuth, // Inject Firebase auth service
        public router: Router,
        public ngZone: NgZone // NgZone service to remove outside scope warning
    ) { }


    /**
     * Update the image or username
     */
    UpdateProfile( displayName ) {
        console.log('In Update profile');
        return this.afAuth.updateProfile({
            displayName: displayName,
            photoURL: "https://example.com/jane-q-user/profile.jpg"

        }).then((result) => {
              console.log('Did the update profile');

        }, function(error){

        });
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 2):

AngularFireAuth.currentUser is an **async** property.
you need to add **await**.

for e.g -

```
async UpdateProfile(displayName: string) {
    const profile = {
        displayName: displayName,
        photoURL: "https://example.com/jane-q-user/profile.jpg"
    }
    return (await this.afAuth.currentUser).updateProfile(profile);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
 return this.afAuth.currentUser.updateProfile({
            displayName: displayName,
            photoURL: "https://example.com/jane-q-user/profile.jpg"

        })
```

> AngularFireAuth promise proxies an initialized `firebase.auth.Auth` instance, allowing you to log users in, out, etc.

[`currentUser`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#currentuser) is a property inside `firebase.auth.Auth` and it returns a instance of `User`.

Comment: That is one of the many things that I have tried. I get an error on the function stating Property 'updateProfile' does not exist on type 'Promise<User>'. It then asks "Did you forget to use 'await'?"

Comment: this.afAuth.currentUser.then((result) => { result.updateProfile()}); can u try this

Comment: OK. So that compiled without an error, but I haven't ran it yet. Is the currentUser method returning a promise to get the current user and then executing the command when the promise is returned? Why does the documentation not reflect this?

Comment: you are using angularfire https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/auth/getting-started.md check the angularfire docs... if you are using pure js usually u just do `var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;` anyway try it and tell me

Answer (score 0):

In Web version 9, this is the method ([documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#update_a_users_profile)):

```js
import { getAuth, updateProfile } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();
updateProfile(auth.currentUser, {    // or you can await the method without callbacks
  displayName: "Jane Q. User", photoURL: "https://example.com/jane-q-user/profile.jpg"
}).then(() => {
  // Profile updated!
  // ...
}).catch((error) => {
  // An error occurred
  // ...
});
```